# Cannot debug python3 program using gdb (py-locals fails)

Tags: python-3.x, gdb

Please find below my dummy program

```
import time
import random

while True:
    print('.', end='', flush=True)
    a = random.randint(1,3)
    b = a*2
    time.sleep(1)
```

I'm running it as follows:

`$ python3 test.py`

Then I'm trying to debug it using gdb... gdb command seem to work:

`sudo gdb -p 31025`

`py-bt` and `py-list` also work:

```
(gdb) py-bt
Traceback (most recent call first):
<built-in method sleep of module object at remote 0x7fe9b8e42f48>
File "test.py", line 9, in <module>
    time.sleep(1)
(gdb) py-list
4    
5    while True:
6        print('.', end='', flush=True)
7        a = random.randint(1,3)
8        b = a*2
>9        time.sleep(1)
(gdb)
```

but py-locals fails:

```
(gdb) py-locals 
Unable to read information on python frame
```

PS. gdb and python3-gdb installed using `sudo apt install gdb python3-dbg`

Comment: Did you fix this issue ?